# Consulta Entity Framework relação Many to Many

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou começando a utilizar o **Entity Framework** e estou querendo fazer uma consulta entre duas tabelas, `Livroes` e `Autors`, e sua relação é do tipo **Many to Many**. Não sei se é relevante mas estou utilizando o método **Code First**, então criei as classes abaixo.

**AUTORES:**

```
class Autor {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

**LIVROS:**

```
class Livro {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Column("EditoraId")]
    public long EditoraId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Autor> Autores { get; set; }
}
```

Não vou colocar a classe editora porque sei como acessá-la e iria ficar muito grande a pergunta, caso necessário edito e coloco depois. Abaixo minha classe **Contexto**

```
class EFContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Editora> Editoras { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Autor> Autores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Autor>()
       .HasMany(autor => autor.Livros)
       .WithMany(livro => livro.Autores)
       .Map(x => {
           x.ToTable("livros_e_autores");
           x.MapLeftKey("autor_id");
           x.MapRightKey("livro_id");
       });
    }

    public EFContext() {
        DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFContext> initializer = new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFContext>();
        Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
    }
}
```

Quando executo o programa devido essa relação **Many to Many** é criada uma nova tabela, chamada **livros_e_autores**, conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que não sei como acessar essa nova tabela que foi criada, tentei fazer um `foreach` dentro de um `foreach` (código abaixo) passando o `ID` do Livro porém o resultado é errado, retornando todos autores para cada livro.

```
public void ListaTodosLivroAutores() {
        using (EFContext ctx = new EFContext()) {
            var retornoLivro = from liv in ctx.Livros
                        select liv;
            foreach(var itemLiv in retornoLivro) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCódigo Livro: " + itemLiv.Id
                                      + "\nNome Livro: " + itemLiv.Nome);

                var retornoAutor = from aut in ctx.Autores
                            where ctx.Livros.Any(l => l.Id == itemLiv.Id)
                            select aut;
                foreach(var itemAut in retornoAutor) {
                    Console.WriteLine("     Autor: " + itemAut.Nome);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Minha duvida é, tem como acessar essa tabela criada pelo relacionamento? Se sim, como? A consulta que queria seria algo parecido com esse `Select` abaixo.

```
SELECT liv.Id "Código Livro",
       liv.Nome "Nome do Livro",
       aut.Nome "Autores"
  FROM dbo.livros_e_autores lea
  INNER JOIN dbo.Livroes liv ON liv.Id = lea.livro_id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Autors aut ON aut.Id = lea.autor_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não precisa acessar essa tabela, basta fazer a consulta:

```
var resultado = ctx.Livros.Include(l=> l.Autores).ToList();
```

ou

```
var resultado = ctx.Livros.Include("Autores").ToList();
```

Para imprimir, por exemplo:

```
foreach (Livro l in resultado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Código Livro: " + l.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + l.Nome);

    foreach (Autor a in l.Autores)
        Console.WriteLine("Autor: " + a.Nome);    

    Console.WriteLine("---------------");

}
```

Comment: agradeço a ajuda mas o método include só aceita string, não tem como transformar essa expressão lambda em string. tentei também passar o resultado de uma consulta convertendo com .ToString também não deu certo

Comment: @GustavoForteAndreli o método Include aceita uma lambda que você informa a propriedade que será incluída no select, ou como string você informa o nome da propriedade. Alterei a resposta, veja se funciona

Comment: ps. Talvez a labda só é aceita no EF Core, depois eu tento confirmar isso

Comment: perfeito, deu certo, agora só vou precisar entender aqui kkkk, mto obrigado.

Comment: Blz, que bom que te atendeu. Bons estudos